# Not able to select a dropdown option with Watir (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, salesforce, watir

I am unable to get Watir to select the correct option from a dropdown. I'm trying to select from this:

```
<select id="j_id0:theForm:ruleTypeSelector" onkeypress="return suppressEnter(event);" size="1" name="j_id0:theForm:ruleTypeSelector">
    <option value="ExecutionOrder">Pricing Administration</option>
    <option value="AccountSpecific">Account Specific Pricing</option>
    <option value="AssociatedProduct">Associated Product Pricing</option>
    <option value="MaintenanceProduct">Maintenance Product Pricing</option>
    <option value="Tiered">Tiered Pricing</option>
    <option value="Volume">Volume Pricing</option>
</select>
```

I need to select the second option, AccountSpecific, but it is not working.

I tried

```
option = browser.select_list(:id => /.*ruleTypeSelector.*/).select("AccountSpecific")
```

and

```
option = browser.select_list(:id => /.*ruleTypeSelector.*/).option(:value => "AccountSpecific")
browser.select_list(:id => /.*ruleTypeSelector.*/)
option.wait_until_present
option.select
browser.button(:value => "Go").click
```

but both times, it instead selects the first option, ExecutionOrder.

Why is this not working?  What else can I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 browser.select_list(:id => /.*ruleTypeSelector.*/).option(:text =>"Account Specific Pricing").when_present.select
```